# My grid item is too large but I cannot control its width

Tags: html, css

I am cloning a webpage.

https://zunnykim.wixsite.com/ancellbioa/pdt-device
Above is the orgininal website that I am cloning. This is how my cloned website is supposed to look like.

I have used css grid to make the layout of the webpage. Everything else was successful except for the fact that the grid item in the top left hand side with the background colour beige, or the grid item #BG_1706588429585_78543 in my codes, is too wide when I render it on the internet. I have tried setting the grid item width and did everything that chat gpt has advised me to do, but nothing worked. I am using a web builder tool called Bluegriffon.

Can you help me find out what is causing the widening of the grid item?

Thanks.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
    <title>PDT-Device</title>
    <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="file:///C:/Users/j/Pictures/ancell%20website/ancell%20website/PDT%20Device.css">
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="grid-container" id="BG_1706588498800_39474">
      <div id="BG_1706588429585_78543"><br>
      </div>
      <div id="BG_1706588472329_93639" style="text-align: center; background-color: #000023;"><span

          style="color: white;"><span style="font-family: avenir-lt-w01_35-light1475496,avenir-lt-w05_35-light,sans-serif; font-size: 14px; font-style: normal; font-variant-ligatures: normal; font-variant-caps: normal; font-weight: 400; letter-spacing: 0.14px; text-align: center; text-indent: 0px; text-transform: none; word-spacing: 0px; -webkit-text-stroke-width: 0px; white-space: normal; text-decoration-style: initial; text-decoration-color: initial; display: inline !important; float: none;">©
            2020 by ANCell-bio co.LTD</span></span></div>
      <div id="BG_1706588554856_71725"><br>
      </div>
      <div id="grid-item4"><br>
        <h1 id="BG_1706591794079_12277"> PDT Device</h1>
        <div class="grid-container">
          <div class="grid-item text-grid-item" style="top: 0px;" id="BG_1706591463850_20525">
            We're going to provide medical devices with light sources that are
            most effective in treating cancer, even in laser devices that are
            very closely linked to drugs. this photo dynamic therapy laser
            device is the best fit for our drugs called photosensitizer.<br>
            <br>
            Laser light is an endoscopic method of examining tumor cells through
            fiber optic. </div>
          <div class="grid-item image-grid-item" id="BG_1706591150784_34941">
            <div class="grid-item text-below-item" style="top: 160px; left: 48px; width: 146px;"

              id="BG_1706593361074_42153">&nbsp;<a href="http://www.atcus.ru/" style="text-decoration: none;"><span

                  style="color: black;" id="BG_1706677155528_4879">&nbsp;&nbsp;More
                  Information</span> </a></div>
            <div class="grid-item image-below-item1" id="BG_1706592847477_13212"

              style="top: 196px; left: 52px; width: 113px;"><br>
            </div>
            <div class="grid-item image-below-item2" id="BG_1706593071441_16638"

              style="top: 196px; left: 169px; width: 244px;"><br>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div id="BG_1706588646571_41284"><br>
        <hr style="width: 750px; height: 1px; color: #000066; border-style: solid; margin-left: auto; margin-right: auto;">
        <div style="text-align: center;" id="BG_1706672008070_78400"><img src="file:///C:/Users/j/Pictures/ancell%20website/ancell%20website/%ED%99%88%ED%8E%98%EC%9D%B4%EC%A7%80%20%EC%86%8C%EC%8A%A4-14.png"

            alt="" style="width: 795px; height: 207px;"></div>
        <div style="text-align: center;" id="BG_1706673018341_89377"><a href="file:///C:/Users/j/Pictures/ancell%20website/ancell%20website/PDT%20LAB.html"

            id="BG_1706673085296_69899">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;BACK&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</a></div>
      </div>
      <div id="BG_1706588715395_3375"><br>
      </div>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

```
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

#BG_1706588429585_78543 {
  -webkit-grid-area: 1 / 1 / span 3 / 1;
  grid-area: 1 / 1 / span 3 / 1;
  background-image: url("");
  background-color: #e4e0db;
}

#BG_1706588472329_93639 {
  -webkit-grid-area: 4 / 1 / 4 / span 3;
  grid-area: 4 / 1 / 4 / span 3;
  height: 200px;
}

#BG_1706588498800_39474 {
  display: grid;
}

#BG_1706588554856_71725 {
  -webkit-grid-area: 1 / 2 / 1 / 2;
  grid-area: 1 / 2 / 1 / 2;
  width: 850px;
  height: 280px;
  background-image: url("file:///C:/Users/j/Pictures/ancell%20website/ancell%20website/GettyImages-1189780516_edited.jpg");
  background-size: cover;
  background-attachment: scroll;
}

#BG_1706588630967_28266 {
  -webkit-grid-area: 2 / 2 / 2 / 2;
  grid-area: 2 / 2 / 2 / 2;
  width: 850px;
  height: 400px;
}

#BG_1706588646571_41284 {
  -webkit-grid-area: 3 / 2 / 3 / 2;
  grid-area: 3 / 2 / 3 / 2;
  height: 400px;
}

#BG_1706588715395_3375 {
  -webkit-grid-area: 1 / 3 / span 3 / 3;
  grid-area: 1 / 3 / span 3 / 3;
  background-color: #e4e0db;
  width: 100px;
  margin-left: -25px; 
}

.grid-container {
  display: grid;
  -webkit-grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr;
  position: relative;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr;
}

.grid-item {
}

.text-grid-item {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0px;
  left: 0px;
  width: 65%;
  padding-left: 50px;
}

.image-grid-item {
  -webkit-grid-area: 1 / 2 / auto / auto;
  grid-area: 1 / 2 / auto / auto;
  height: 350px;
  width: 400px;
}

.text-below-item {
  -webkit-grid-area: auto / auto / auto / auto;
  grid-area: auto / auto / auto / auto;
  position: absolute;
}

.image-below-item {
  -webkit-grid-area: 3 / 1 / auto / auto;
  grid-area: 3 / 1 / auto / auto;
  position: absolute;
}

.image-below-item img {
  max-width: 100%;
}

#BG_1706591150784_34941 {
  background-image: url("2240.jpg");
  background-size: cover;
}

#BG_1706591463850_20525 {
  height: 150px;
  z-index: 1;
}

#BG_1706593071441_16638 {
  position: absolute;
  height: 160px;
  width: 384px;
  background-image: url("stomatology1.jpg");
  background-size: cover;
}

#BG_1706592847477_13212 {
  position: absolute;
  width: 80px;
  height: 160px;
  background-image: url("stomatology2.jpg");
  background-size: cover;
}

#BG_1706593361074_42153 {
  font-family: "Bahnschrift";
  border-radius: 20px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  text-decoration: none;
}

#BG_1706672008070_78400 {
  margin: 40px;
}

#BG_1706591794079_12277 {
  padding-left: 50px;
  font-family: "Bahnschrift";
}

#BG_1706673018341_89377 {
  text-decoration: none;
}

#BG_1706673085296_69899 {
  text-decoration: none;
  font-family: "Bahnschrift";
  border: 1px solid black;
  border-radius: 20px;
  color: white;
  background-color: #002121;
}

#BG_1706677155528_4879 {
  text-decoration: none;
}
```